# Makefile: Pass argument to recipe of dependency in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a make target called `upstream` and it has a dependency called `downstream`.

I want to execute the `upstream` target with an argument say `MY_HASH` which I will specify at runtime and in turn use in the recipe of my dependency i.e. `downstream`.

Something like this:
`make upstream MY_HASH=latest` (OR) `make upstream MY_HASH=123abc` etc.

I want to use this `MY_HASH` (`latest`/`123abc`) in the recipe of my dependency `downstream`.

How can I achieve this?

This is my pseudocode till now

```
upstream : downstream
downstream :
        my_script.sh $(MY_HASH)
```

How and where can I write that `MY_HASH` in `upstream` so that it can be leveraged in its dependency's target?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?  Do you need `${MY_HASH}` as a dependency of `downstream`?  Or do you need to run `myscript.sh ${MY_HASH}` to build `downstram` or to run after building `downstream`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan!
I need to use `MY_HASH` to build `downstream` but this MY_HASH needs to come from the `upstream` i.e. `make upstream MY_HASH=xyz`.

Basically I need to use `MY_HASH` in the recipe of downstream but I want to specify it while running `upstream`.  Also, `MY_HASH` will vary from command to command.
In other words, I want to tell make that `upstream` is going to be run with one argument i.e. `MY_HASH` which will be utilized in the recipe of the dependency `downstream`

Comment: Do I not need to modify something in the `upstream` target code for it to understand that this target will accept an argument with which it needs to pass down to it's dependency i.e. `downstream`?
I was looking to understand how to syntactically do this Make.

Comment: Does the makefile need to build `${MY_HASH}` or is it just taken for granted?  I'm still not clear on the sequence of commands you expect to see run by make.  Are the `upstream` and `downstream` targets 'phoney' — do they create files (programs) called `upstream` and `downstream`?

Answer (score 1):

Variables specified on command-line are applied *globally*, and so will apply for all recipes. `make upstream MY_HASH=xyz` will set `MY_HASH` for `downstream` as well.

If you think `MY_HASH` is only to be defined for a specific target, you could make your intent more clear with a target specific variable. From the docs:

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites.

Example usage:

```
# downstream is prerequisite of target upstream
upstream : downstream

# MY_HASH to be used by upstream and prerequisites (recursively)
# abc123 used as default (zero filled is probably a better choice for default hash)
upstream : MY_HASH ?= abc123

downstream :
        my_script.sh $(MY_HASH)
```

Passing global variable value by command line will override the target specific variable.

**WARNING**: Make will NOT consider changes in command line parameters to determine whether a target is out-of-date. You'd need a file with the hash as content, or a file whose name is partly made up from the hash (my preference).